# Why won't my first_name field send to database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, user-input

I'm using a comment form with a first name field that is supposed to send to the database with the comments, but for some reason even though I have the column first_name in the database it won't send, any suggestions?

P.S
I am aware of any SQL Injection vulnerabilities but thank you for being concerned! I plan to just focus on this problem before going further.
Thank you for helping!

```
<?php
session_start();

$loggedIn = false;

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $loggedIn = true;
}

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '', '', 'profiles2');

function createCommentRow($data) {
    global $conn;

    $response = '
            <div class="comment">
                <div class="user">'.$data['name'].' <span class="time">'.$data['createdOn'].'</span></div>
                <div class="userComment">'.$data['comment'].'</div>
                <div class="reply"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-commentID="'.$data['id'].'" onclick="reply(this)">REPLY</a></div>
                <div class="replies">';

    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT replies.id, name, comment, DATE_FORMAT(replies.createdOn, '%Y-%m-%d') AS createdOn FROM replies INNER JOIN users ON replies.userID = users.id WHERE replies.commentID = '".$data['id']."' ORDER BY replies.id DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($dataR = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        $response .= createCommentRow($dataR);

    $response .= '
                        </div>
            </div>
        ';

    return $response;
}

if (isset($_POST['getAllComments'])) {
    $start = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['start']);

    $response = "";
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT comments.id, name, comment, DATE_FORMAT(comments.createdOn, '%Y-%m-%d') AS createdOn FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.id ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT $start, 20");
    while($data = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        $response .= createCommentRow($data);

    exit($response);
}

if (isset($_POST['addComment'])) {
    $comment = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
    $isReply = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['isReply']);
    $commentID = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['commentID']);
    $first_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
    if ($isReply != 'false') {
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO replies (comment, commentID, userID, createdOn) VALUES ('$comment', '$commentID', '".$_SESSION['userID']."', NOW())");
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT replies.id, name, comment, DATE_FORMAT(replies.createdOn, '%Y-%m-%d') AS createdOn FROM replies INNER JOIN users ON replies.userID = users.id ORDER BY replies.id DESC LIMIT 1");
    } else {
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO comments (userID, first_name, comment, createdOn) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['userID']."','".$first_name."','$comment',NOW())");
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT comments.id, name, comment, DATE_FORMAT(comments.createdOn, '%Y-%m-%d') AS createdOn FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.id ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 1");
    }

    $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();
    exit(createCommentRow($data));
}

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0)
            exit('failedUserExists');
        else {
            $ePassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $conn->query("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password,createdOn) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$ePassword', NOW())");

            $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
            $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();

            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $data['id'];

            exit('success');
        }
    } else
        exit('failedEmail');
}

if (isset($_POST['logIn'])) {
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $sql = $conn->query("SELECT id, password, name FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        if ($sql->num_rows == 0)
            exit('failed');
        else {
            $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();
            $passwordHash = $data['password'];

            if (password_verify($password, $passwordHash)) {
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $data['name'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $data['id'];

                exit('success');
            } else
                exit('failed');
        }
    } else
        exit('failed');
}

$sqlNumComments = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM comments");
$numComments = $sqlNumComments->num_rows;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>YouTube Comment System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
        .comment {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .user {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
        }

        .time, .reply {
            color: gray;
        }

        .userComment {
            color: #000;
        }

        .replies .comment {
            margin-top: 20px;

        }

        .replies {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        #registerModal input, #logInModal input {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal" id="registerModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Registration Form</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" id="userName" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                <input type="email" id="userEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                <input type="password" id="userPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="registerBtn">Register</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="logInModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Log In Form</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="email" id="userLEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                <input type="password" id="userLPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="loginBtn">Log In</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" align="right">
            <?php
            if (!$loggedIn)
                echo '
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logInModal">Log In</button>
                ';
            else
                echo '
                    <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-warning">Log Out</a>
                ';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u2O_QyPfdpE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
    <form action="search_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <button>Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form method="POST" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name...">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="mainComment" placeholder="Add Public Comment" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Comment" style="float:right" class="btn-primary btn" onclick="isReply = false;" id="addComment">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2><b id="numComments"><?php echo $numComments ?> Comments</b></h2>
            <div class="userComments">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row replyRow" style="display:none">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="replyComment" placeholder="Add Public Comment" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea><br>
        <button style="float:right" class="btn-primary btn" onclick="isReply = true;" id="addReply">Add Reply</button>
        <button style="float:right" class="btn-default btn" onclick="$('.replyRow').hide();">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isReply = false, commentID = 0, max = <?php echo $numComments ?>;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addComment, #addReply").on('click', function () {
            var comment;

            if (!isReply)
                comment = $("#mainComment").val();
            else
                comment = $("#replyComment").val();

            if (comment.length > 5) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        addComment: 1,
                        comment: comment,
                        isReply: isReply,
                        commentID: commentID
                    }, success: function (response) {
                        max++;
                        $("#numComments").text(max + " Comments");

                        if (!isReply) {
                            $(".userComments").prepend(response);
                            $("#mainComment").val("");
                        } else {
                            commentID = 0;
                            $("#replyComment").val("");
                            $(".replyRow").hide();
                            $('.replyRow').parent().next().append(response);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else
                alert('Please Check Your Inputs');
        });

        $("#registerBtn").on('click', function () {
            var name = $("#userName").val();
            var email = $("#userEmail").val();
            var password = $("#userPassword").val();

            if (name != "" && email != "" && password != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        register: 1,
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }, success: function (response) {
                        if (response === 'failedEmail')
                            alert('Please insert valid email address!');
                        else if (response === 'failedUserExists')
                            alert('User with this email already exists!');
                        else
                            window.location = window.location;
                    }
                });
            } else
                alert('Please Check Your Inputs');
        });

        $("#loginBtn").on('click', function () {
            var email = $("#userLEmail").val();
            var password = $("#userLPassword").val();

            if (email != "" && password != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        logIn: 1,
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    }, success: function (response) {
                        if (response === 'failed')
                            alert('Please check your login details!');
                        else
                            window.location = window.location;
                    }
                });
            } else
                alert('Please Check Your Inputs');
        });

        getAllComments(0, max);
    });

    function reply(caller) {
        commentID = $(caller).attr('data-commentID');
        $(".replyRow").insertAfter($(caller));
        $('.replyRow').show();
    }

    function getAllComments(start, max) {
        if (start > max) {
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                getAllComments: 1,
                start: start
            }, success: function (response) {
                $(".userComments").append(response);
                getAllComments((start+20), max);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should debug, we can't do it for you.. meaning enabling PHP to run in "debug" mode more or less include at the start (index.php) -> `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: Also beside SQL injection your code is also prone to race conditions.. `$sql = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        if ($sql->num_rows > 0)
            exit('failedUserExists');
        else {
            $ePassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` is vulnerable.. Your table should have a unique key on the email column..

Comment: Also the added code is much more then is required to reproduce the problem? See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you are making an Ajax call with addComment set to 1, but you are not sending the first_name, you are only sending comment, commentID and isReply.

Your form needs an ID on the first_name

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="first_name" id='first_name' placeholder="First Name...">
```

Then, send the first name value in your addComment ajax call like this:

First, get the value of first_name
    var first_name = $("first_name").val()
...
Then add it to ajax call:

```
data: {
                    first_name:first_name,
                    addComment: 1,
                    comment: comment,
                    isReply: isReply,
                    commentID: commentID
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to send the first_name with ajax

Comment: Ok, thanks! I am trying it right away!                                                   
So the PHP I did correctly, no mistakes?

Comment: Hello, Jack Albright! I have tried the code the you suggested and it works! The only problem is that when we search the first name in the search bar, the comment doesn't show up, I can add the code I used later on, if that will be helpful.

Comment: Najma, try using console.log to examine the  value of comment value prior to making the ajax call. Also, your comment form element does not have a name (it only has an ID). This should still work, but it is not good form. Also, look in the database itself and see if the comment value is ever inserted.

Comment: Thank you Jack, the code worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Hello Mr albright I truly aplogize for not marking your answer as correct i will do that right away